# Homework, write a function that converts a string of digits into an integer

Tags: c, for-loop, integer-overflow, function-definition

I know I could have found the code page on the Internet easily enough for that function, but I want to know why, after passing the 10 digit array, the expected result doesn't act like the previous ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int xstraylen(char *arr) {
    int len;
    
    for (len = 0; *(arr + len) != '\0'; len++) {
        //printf("%c ", *(arr + len));
    }
    return len;
}

int str_into_int(char *str) {
    int power = 10, len, number;
    long int value = 0;
    
    len = xstraylen(str);
    printf("\n%d\n", len);

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        number = (int)(*(str + index) - 48);
        value += number;
        value *= power;
        printf("-%d- %d %d ", index, number, value);
    }

    value /= power;

    return value;
}

int main() {    
    char *str = "1234567890";  
    int value;
    
    value = str_into_int(str);
    printf("\n\n%d", value);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
10

-0- 1 10 -1- 2 120 -2- 3 1230 -3- 4 12340 -4- 5 123450 -5- 6 1234560 -6- 7 12345670 -7- 8 123456780 -8- 9 1234567890 -9- 0 -539222988 

-53922298
```

Comment: `printf("-%d- %d %d ", index, number, value);` => `printf("-%d- %d %ld ", index, number, value);`. You must use `%ld` to print a variable of type `long int`.

Comment: You absolutely right, but the error does not change. I thought that it was a problem of size of "int" but it isn't, apparently @LucaPolito

Comment: Please, add the output that you *want* the function to print.

Comment: You know `*(str + index)` is just `str[index]` right?

Comment: Also, I recommend you write `'0'` rather than `48`. It makes it much clearer why you're adding something, rather than an arbitrary number.

Comment: And you should verify if the character is actually a digit before attempting to use it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work for 10 digit numbers because you always multiply `value` by 10 in the loop after adding the digit and divide it at the end. For a 10 digit number, the last multiplication causes an arithmetic overflow on your platform where both `int` and `long` probably have 32 bits.

You should multiply `value` before adding the digit and remove the final division:

```
int str_into_int(char *str) {
    int power = 10, len, number;
    long int value = 0;
    
    len = xstraylen(str);
    printf("\n%d\n", len);

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        value *= power;
        number = (int)(*(str + index) - 48);
        value += number;
        printf("-%d- %d %ld ", index, number, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Note that the code can be further simplified and modified to handle larger values and detect overflow:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int str_into_int(const char *str) {
    unsigned long long int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'; i++) {
        unsigned int digit = str[i] - '0';
        if (value > ULLONG_MAX / 10 ||
            (value == ULLONG_MAX / 10 && digit > ULLONG_MAX % 10)) {
                printf("conversion exceeds range of unsigned long long\n");
                return ULLONG_MAX;
            }
        value = value * 10 + digit;
    }
    return value;
}

void test(const char *str) {
    printf("%s -> %llu\n", str, str_into_int(str));
}

int main() {
    test("1234567890");
    test("12345678901234567890");
    test("18446744073709551615");
    test("18446744073709551616");
    test("123456789012345678901234567890");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1234567890 -> 1234567890
12345678901234567890 -> 12345678901234567890
18446744073709551615 -> 18446744073709551615
conversion exceeds range of unsigned long long
18446744073709551616 -> 18446744073709551615
conversion exceeds range of unsigned long long
123456789012345678901234567890 -> 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: +1 good answer. Minor note: your `long long int str_into_int()` function doesn't handle integer overflows. Plus: since you don't handle negative numbers, it's worth using `unsigned long long` so you have even a higher range.

Comment: @LucaPolito: indeed I didn't... handling overflow is not difficult and will how many readers how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler considers the type `long int` as having the same range of values as the type `int`.

In this expression statement

```
value *= power;
```

there an overflow occurs when value is equal to `1234567890`.

Change the logic of the for loop the following way

```
for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    value *= power;
    number = *(str + index) - '0';
    value += number;
    printf("-%d- %d %ld ", index, number, value);
}
```

and remove this statement

```
value /= power;
```

Bear in mind that your function does not process a sign mark.

Take into account the function `xstraylen` should be declared the following way

```
size_t xstraylen( const char *arr ) {
    size_t len = 0;
    
    while ( *( arr + len ) ) ++len;

    return len;
}
```

Comment: ahhh know I understood, much thanks @Vlad form Moscow

Comment: && also @ chqrlie